# cakephp saveall Error Argument #2 is not an array

Tags: php, cakephp

So I have a piece of code that has worked for months now on my localhost and development server. Both of which are windows environments. When moved to a new linux hosting location it throws these errors:

Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 2036]

Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 2186]

The piece of code in question is a saveAll call that saves data retrieved from a form. Interestingly the data still saves despite the error.

The code for my save is here

```
            if (!($quote['Quote']['total'] == 0 || $quote['Quote']['total'] < 0)) {
            if ($this->Quote->saveAll($quote, true)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Quote Saved', 'success');
                $this->redirect('/clientcases/view/' . $case . '#tab6');
            }
```

The entire function:

```
    public function makeQuote() {
    $this->loadModel('Applicant');
    $this->LoadModel('ApplicantQuote');
    $this->LoadModel('Setfee');
    $this->LoadModel('Clientcase');
    $this->LoadModel('Internalprice');
    $this->LoadModel('Clientprice');

    /* ------ retrieving client and internal prices for display ------ */
    $internal = $this->Internalprice->find('all');
    $client = $this->Clientprice->find('all');

    //retrieves the applicants chosen from the view_quotes page
    $args = $this->params['url'];
    //get the case id from the previous page

    $case = $args['data']['caseid'];
    //remove move some unnecessary things from the args array
    unset($args['data']['caseid']);
    unset($args['id']);
    //retrieve the applicant information from the database using the applicant array
    $applicants = $this->Applicant->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $args['data']),
        'order' => 'first_name ASC', 'recursive' => -1));

    $app_id = Set::classicExtract($applicants, '{n}.Applicant.id');

    if ($applicants == null) {//redirect back to view quotes page if no applicants were chosen
        $this->Session->setflash('Choose at least one applicant');
        $this->redirect('/clientcases/view/' . $case . '#tab5');
    }

    $this->set(compact('applicants', 'case', 'args', 'internal', 'client'));

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $cancelCheck = $_POST;
        if ($cancelCheck['QuoteButton'] == 'Cancel') {
            $this->redirect('/clientcases/view/' . $case);
        }

        $quote = $this->request->data;
        unset($quote['QuoteButton']);

        $quote["Applicant"] = array();
        $quote['Applicant']['Applicant'] = array();

        $count = 0;
        foreach ($app_id as $key => $id) {
            $quote['Applicant']['Applicant'][] = $app_id[$count];
            $count++;
        }

        $gst = 0;
        if ($quote['Quote']['includeGST'] == 1) {
            $total = $quote['Quote']['total'];

            if ($total > 0) {
                $gst = $total / 10;
            }
        }
        $quote['Quote']['GST'] = $gst;
            //debug($quote);
        unset($quote['Quote']['includeGST']);
        if (!($quote['Quote']['total'] == 0 || $quote['Quote']['total'] < 0)) {
            if ($this->Quote->saveAll($quote, true)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Quote Saved', 'success');
                $this->redirect('/clientcases/view/' . $case . '#tab6');
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setflash('Quote Failed to Save, All fields must be filled in and total greater than 0');
        }
    }
}
```

The data still saves just fine but how do I change it so that it doesn't throw those errors?

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter for [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) is an array. You are sending boolean.

In  your case, it looks like `save($quote)` would work too. The second parameter for `save` is boolean, so that will not return an error.

Maybe the warnings were suppressed on the other servers.

Comment: I don't think just a save would work. The form is trying to save to 5 different tables at once.